# Is there a Persian Transliteration App

Tags: online-learning, transliteration, persian

The question says it all... I'm looking for a google translate-type app/website, where I can type in english phrases and have them be transliterated from Farsi :)  Right now, I can't read the arabic alphabet enough so that Google is useful :0

For example, I'm looking for an app/website which I can use in conversation with my persian friends, that displays the sentences I want to say in english phonetic form.

Comment: Welcome to languagelearning.SE. Could you add an explicit context of language learning to the question?

Comment: I tried to update it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Behnevis](https://behnevis.com/en/) to transliterate from the so-called *Finglish* to Persian, and vice-versa. For the long vowels, make sure to use double letters; e.g. "salaam" instead of "salam" or "saalem" instead of "salem".

Google Translate also has the option from Finglish to Persian:

[image: Google Translate Transliteration for Persian]

Comment: But can you do english to Finglish

Comment: @AIM_BLB what do you mean?

Comment: @Neeku I just tried to use Behnevis but i can only transliterate from Finglish to Persian, not the other way.

Comment: I think what AIM_BLB is asking about is combining translation and transliteration in one step. Right now we need to translate «hello» to «سلام» in Google translate, then copy and paste the result to some transliteration app to convert it so «slam» and guess that it should be pronounced «salam». The last step can't really be automated, but a dictionary that translates «hello» directly to «salam» or even «slam» would be a great help for learners.

Comment: I honestly don’t know if there should even be thoughts of doing such a thing. Do other languages like Hindi, Georgian, Arminian, Russian, Japanese or Chinese have such tools? The script is part of the language learning. Yes it is different and maybe difficult to learn but that’s the only difficulty about learning Persian; no cases, no genders, etc.

Comment: I know I'm late here, but I want this kind of a tool as well. @neeku, I feel your perspective is extremely narrow and damaging to learners. Not everybody wants to learn a language to be able to read and write in that language. Some just want to have casual conversations. As to your question about if such tools exist, yes! Many tools exist for both Chinese (pinyin) as well as Japanese (romaji). Google Translate now also shows the transliteration for both Chinese and Japanese translations (although this is a recent development). It's been very frustrating to try to learn farsi because of this.

Comment: Just to add a little more context (I'm past the edit window for comments): Google Translate now shows the transliteration for ALL of the languages that Neeku challenged with (Hindi, Georgian, Armenian, Russian, Chinese and Japanese), although admittedly this is a recent development. It's been very frustrating to try to learn farsi because of the lack of such a tool.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [app](http://mylanguages.org/farsi_romanization.php).

There is also an interesting discussion in Wikipedia about [different paradigms for transliterating Farsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Persian)

Comment: Hey, Ya that website is okay (I saw it also) but it doesn't understand the vowels usually :(

Comment: Short vowels are not written in Persian. Native speakers know how to pronounce the word because they already know it, learners need to do some guessing. There is no way for an app to guess the sound correctly 100%. Transliteration should only converts the script, it shouldn't fill the gaps at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have done an attempt to make such an app — at least parts of what I think you're looking for ;)

However, it only works for **single words** and not phrases. And there is only an **Android** version of the app: see [Lingographer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zamenhof.lingographer) on Google Play.

**More importantly:**
Unfortunately, to be frank, the Farsi transliteration works so-and-so for less common words (I hope I can improve it further at some point).

[image: Screenshot from the app]

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a google online transliteration tool
https://www.google.com/intl/fa/inputtools/try/